# Why my Windows Server 2012 "server" server for folder sharing crashes?

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share

Last week my Windows Server 2012 "server" service has a daily crash after lunch time.
The effect is that all network shared folders becomes not accessible.
I solved restarting the "server" service, sometimes I could not stop it and I had to restart the VM.

What really sounds strange for me is that it happens after lunch time.

Looking inside sessions and open files of the server share I saw that randomly some user had hundreds of opened folders. Users with high n. of opened files change randomly and when I asked them how many folder were they using they replies just a few.

Users of my company use all the same mapped network drive.

I really don't know of this opened file fact has something to do with the server crash.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only hint I have:

Could be the Windows search indexing? This can answer why it blocks at lunch time (when many PC are on but without activity) and why randomly users have many opened folders.

I tried to exclude from indexing path the mapped network drives by GPO. I will see if this is the answer, therefore I cannot understand why my server crashes and why it happends in last week and not before.